# Inverted i.e., top-to-bottom RecycleView in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

**Context:** I am making a simple chat app client in Kivy for my own chat app API (irrelevant but made using DRF). I have implemented a RecycleView for the 'chats' and working on the messages feature.

**Problem:** I needed an inverted RecycleView in which the views are shown from bottom-to-top to show messages as in WhatsApp for example. I have not been able to find any relevant solution on the internet. Is it even possible (using Kivy's built-in features)?

**Code**: This is how I have implemented my chats recycle view UI.
`Python`

```
class ChatItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    index = None
    data = None

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        self.data = data

        self.ids.name_label.text = self.data['other_user_data']['display_name']
        _ = self.data['other_user_data']['profile_picture']
        self.ids.profile_picture_image.source = App.get_running_app().root.manager.base_url + str(_).removeprefix('/') if _ is not None else DEFAULT_PROFILE_PICTURE_PATH

        return super(ChatItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_release(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.on_chat_click(self.data)


class ChatsRecycleView(RecycleView):
    pass
```

`Kivy Language`

```
<ChatItem>:
    # canvas for debuging
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
        Line:
            width: 1
            points: self.x, self.y, self.x + self.width, self.y

    size_hint_y: None
    padding: dp(5)

    AsyncImage:
        id: profile_picture_image
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(55), dp(55)

    Label:
        id: name_label

<ChatsRecycleView>
    viewclass: 'ChatItem'

    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(65)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Comment: I don't know of any parameter to achieve this, but you can set the data of your RV to `data[::-1]` to get the order in reverse and scroll to the bottom with `your_rv.scroll_y = 0`